# Y Value labels in plot function

Tags: r, plot

I need to add Y value labels next to my plot and I tried text function but no luck here - it only prints my X values.
Any sugestions? Isn't such functionality achievable as an argument to plot function?

My second smaller question is how to print all values on X axis not only every fifth as I have now

Thanks In advance!

Comment: I want to have Y values next to points on a plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(1)
y<-rnorm(10)
set.seed(2)
x<-rnorm(10)
plot(x,y)
text(x, y, labels=round(y,2),pos=3)
```

For your second question, you can use `?axis` function:

```
plot(x,y,xaxt="n") #don't draw x-axis
 #draw x-axis by spesifying the ticks using argument at for function axis
axis(side=1,at=x,labels=round(x,2)) #this makes ticks only for values in x
text(x, y, labels=round(y,2),pos=4)
```